# Magento 1.9.2.4 Category Layout problem

Tags: category, layout, magento1.9.2.4

I have a problem with my category layout. Sometimes there is a gap between products list, just like a product is missed.

[image: category]

Any ideas how to solve this riddle?

Thank you.

Comment: Provide me site link... i think it's css issue for li section..

Comment: Just change .products-grid .item css min-height : 496px to    height: 540px;..

Comment: Yes,  that done now! Thanks for your interest!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### CSS solution

This is related to the product heights, the quickest fix is to set a height on the product listing's `.item` (unless you've altered the classes).

For example:

```
.products-grid .item {
    height: 200px;
}
```

Keep in mind you may need to set the height to be different across different breakpoints.

I've just checked the site you're referring to and the fix is to change the `min-height` to something like `550px`.

Screenshot:[image]

### JS solution

For a more in depth solution you could use javascript, along the lines of getting the tallest `.item` and setting the other's to be the same height. Even better you could do this per row of products. There are plugins for this such as http://brm.io/jquery-match-height/

Comment: Smart people on magento.stackexchange! Thank you for this, worked perfect. I might consider using the JS solution later on :) Thank you once more!

Answer (score 1):

Just change css from

```
.products-grid .item
{
min-height : 496px
}
```

to

```
.products-grid .item
{
min-height : 540px
}
```

Your issue is solve.

Comment: Yes, both answers work perfectly fine!

Comment: Smart guy you @Nikul :D